# Number of arguments in macro definition

Tags: c++, macros, arguments, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have some templated function which has different number of arguments due to the template-type. This function is wrapped with macro definition.

```
#define SomeTemplate(TemplateType, Arguments) someFunc<TemplateType>(Arguments);
```

Everything is okay when I'm using only one argument for function calling, but I need in more. I looked at boost it does such things through definition of different macros, like this:

```
#define TEMP_1(Arg1) someFunc<Template>(Arg1);
#define TEMP_2(Arg1, Arg2) someFunc<Template>(Arg1, Arg2);
#define TEMP_3(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3) someFunc<Template>(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3);
```

But this code marked as portable for compilers. There is way to use some defines with any number of arguments. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need this at all?  Why not just use the templated function directly, without macros?

Comment: @doublep because calling is a lot bigger and takes more place. I've simplied it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the  only  way to do that us using `__VA__ARGS__` in  the macro definations, however, its not as portable, beacuse older compilers like VC6 doesn't support var arg'ed macros, see:
[MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415%28VS.80%29.aspx)
[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about VC6: it doesn't support C++.

Comment: it supports C++ alright (I use it for legacy development), you just can't get too carried away with templates and macros, plus you need so use a better STL, VC6's one (as a friend describes it) is AIDS